# Limit Number of Posts coming from /feed Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use /{page_id}/feed?access_token=xxxx, this give me all the posts on the page, both by user and page. I want to limit and control the posts. I want to put constraints like:

1. Timestamp (that is to get posts after a particular timestamp)
2. Post id (to get post after a particular post)

Since getting all the posts from feed is irrelevant and in-effective. Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: I think you should Mark Tobi's answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: Not enough reputation. Just 6. Need 15.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
GET /{page_id}/feed?limit={nr_of_posts_to_return}&since={timestamp}
```

to be able to limit the number of results and specify the starting timestamp. Have a look at the reference here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#paging

For your second Use Case you'd need to use the **Batch API** imho, because with a single Graph API request you can't filter on specific `Posts`. Instead, you need to use the Batch API to split this in two queries as described here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#operations

The request would then look like this:

```
curl \
    -F 'access_token={your_access_token}' \
    -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-post","relative_url":"{your_post_id}?fields=created_time"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"{your_page_id}/feed?since={result=get-post:$.created_time}&limit={nr_of_posts_to_return}"}]' \
    https://graph.facebook.com/
```

In Graph Explorer, you have to change the HTTP method to `Post`, then add a new field called `batch`. Leave the URL blank so far. Paste this as `batch` value:

```
[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-post","relative_url":"​293088074081904_400071946716849?fields=created_time"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"293088074081904/feed?since={result=get-post:$.created_time}&limit=1"}]
```

This works at least for me.

Comment: Hey Tobi. I need to replicate what I am doing in FQL due to the announcement that FQL is being removed after version 2.0. Your batch example looks very close to part of what I need to achieve, are you able to give an actual example which I can paste into Graph API explorer? I am getting
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:    batch=[{\"method\":\"GET\",\"name\":\"get-post\",\"relative_url\":\"132008873631170_297886753710047", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 803
  }
}
So I assume my post ID is the wrong format?
Thanks Heaps!!

Comment: yes, the post_id is not correct. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tobi
Looks like there is a few other things I do in FQL that I cannot replicate with graph.. so end of the line for me.
Thanks for your update.. much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, but what do you mean with "other things I do in FQL that I cannot replicate with graph"? You can mix FQL with "normal" Graph API requests even in one batch... And, please be aware that FQL will only work until April 30th 2015!

Comment: According to what I have read is that it is supported until version 2.1, so April 30th 2016. Graph interface does not let me get updated comments on a page. You need to troll every post and look at every updated time. That's bad enough, but replies are not even included in the /comments you need to check each comment for them.. and the final nail for me is that the replies have no create_time

So currently I have a product that uses FQL for 90% of what I need. I cannot replicate it all in graph.. so I am pulling the plug on the last year of development I have done..was releasing it this month!

Comment: For Tobi
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

FQL is still available in version 2.0, but will not be available in the next version of the API. This early warning is given so that developers can start migrating off FQL to the Graph API as soon as possible. We strongly recommend that developers build no new experiences based on FQL. The vast majority of use cases can be achieved using the Graph API including field expansion and batched requests.

Comment: What about `/102099916530784/posts?limit=10&fields=id,message,comments.since(1400112000).limit(10).fields(message,created_time,like_count,comments.fields(message,created_time))` for example?

Comment: You're right, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#howlong says that v2.0 will be available for 2 years, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_fql says that FQL will be part of v2.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52729/discussion-between-rob-den-boer-and-tobi)

Comment: `/102099916530784/posts?since=1400065200&fields=id,message,comments.since(1400104800).fields(message,created_time,like_count,comments.since(1400140800))` does the job for Rob's problem I think

Comment: The 'since' done at the 'comment' and 'reply' levels are ignored. 

The query Tobi provided will provide all the posts after the first 'since' but every comment and reply in those posts, regardless of that you set their 'since' to.

If you wish to search for new comments , regardless of the age of the post, this fails as well. For example:remove the first 'since' and change to limit=1000 and only request comments as a fields using 'since' , this will return the last 1000 posts and all comments for all of those 1000.

Thanks Tobi for your time.. really appreciated it

Comment: Hi, I have a question on the same lines. For the first use case, when you say limit={nr_of_posts_to_return}, what is the maximum number that can be passed to the limit? This was the only thread I found online which was talking about limits.

Comment: @harshit See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading chapter **Cursor-based Pagination**: `limit` : This is the number of individual objects that are returned in each page. Note that this is an upper limit, if there are not enough remaining objects in the list of data, then less than this number will be returned. Some edges have an upper maximum on the limit value, for performance reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if that happens.

Comment: Thanks @Tobi So, if I understand it right, limit for each kind of is different and has to set dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

For others looking for a solution, it appears the 'since' done at the 'comment' and 'reply' levels are ignored. Which means this is not a solution for me.

The query Tobi provided will provide all the posts after the first 'since' but every comment and reply in those posts, regardless of that you set their 'since' to.

Further to this, if you wish to search for new comments , regardless of the age of the post, this fails as well.  For example:remove the first 'since' and change to limit=1000 and only request comments as a fields using 'since' , this will return the last 1000 posts and all comments for all of those 1000.

That said, thank you Tobi for your time and showing me how to get everything I need in a single function call. I may experiment parsing the complete recordset every time. ( maybe too much traffic though!)